# How to make the operating system run multiple "forked" processes on different processor cores?

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I use Debian. When I run parent process from user in terminal, "forked" processes are run on different processor cores. But the parent-process is run from rc.local with root permission, all "forked" process are run on the same processor core as the parent core. How to make the processes running under root is distributed to the processor cores as well as if we ran under a standard user?

Comment: Is the stated behaviour documented somewhere, or is it just something you have observed? Why do you want to distribute processes across other cores? Have you tried using `taskset` to change affinity?

Comment: htop showed me loading only one core at startup "forked" processes.I want to distribute processes across other cores because one core don't cope with tasks. I didn't try using taskset but I will try. Thank you for advice.

Comment: I tried taskset. It didn't work when i had started my program from rc.local